# C++ Char Class Operator< function compare

Tags: c++, string, class, overloading, operator-keyword

```
bool String::operator < (const String &s) const 
{
int len1 = s.getLength();
int len2 = this->getLength();
int cap;
if(len1>len2) cap = len2;
else cap = len1;
int index=0;
for (int i =0; i < cap;i++)
    if (this->buffer[i] != s[i])
        index =i;
for (int i= index; i < cap; i++)
    if (this->buffer[i] < s[i])
        return true;
for (int i= index; i < cap; i++)
    if (this->buffer[i] > s[i])
        return false;
if (*this == s)
    return false;
if (len2>len1)
    return false;
if (len2<len1)
    return true;
}
```

I have been working with this overloading operator< that compares two strings.

It's working successfully. I test every case that possible.

But when I F7 the program, it still shows up 'String::operator<' : not all control paths return a value.

Please tell me what am I missing in this function?

Comment: If you are sure you've handled all cases, then you can drop `if (len2<len1)` condition before the last `return` - it has to always be true if indeed it's the last remaining case.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah I tried to drop the last if away, but if I do that it will the result won't be correct
Eg: "Test" and "Test1"

Comment: If dropping the last condition changes the result, then you haven't handled all possible cases. If you arrive at `if (len2<len1)` line and it turns out that the condition doesn't hold and `len2` is in fact equal to `len1`, then your function falls off without returning, and the compiler is correct to complain. If at that line `len2` is always less than `len1`, then the condition is always true and dropping the check shouldn't alter the result. You can't have it both ways; you are making two claims that contradict each other.

Comment: Off the top, your function declares `"bb" < "ac"`. Did you mean it this way?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah when I try "bb" and "ac" it shows wrong result... why tho

Comment: Because your algorithm says so. Now would be a good time to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If your loops don't `return`, and if `*this == s` is false (you shouldn't be doing that comparison in this function), and if `len2>len1` and `len2<len1` are both false (meaning `len2==len1` is true), then you are indeed missing a final `return`, which is what the compiler is warning you about.

```
bool String::operator < (const String &s) const 
{
    ...

    if (len2>len1)
        return false;
    if (len2<len1)
        return true;

    // IF YOU REACH HERE, THERE IS NO RETURN!
}
```

That being said, your code can be simplified a bit:

```cpp
bool String::operator < (const String &s) const 
{
    int len1 = this->getLength();
    int len2 = s.getLength();
    int cap = (len1 < len2) ? len1 : len2;
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i) {
        if (this->buffer[i] != s[i]) {
            return (this->buffer[i] < s[i]);
        }
    }
    return (len1 < len2);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::mismatch()`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

bool String::operator < (const String &s) const 
{
    int len1 = this->getLength();
    int len2 = s.getLength();
    int cap = std::min(len1, len2);
    const char* buffer_end = this->buffer + cap;
    std::pair<const char*, const char*> ret = std::mismatch(this->buffer, buffer_end, s.buffer);
    return (ret.first != buffer_end)
        ? (*ret.first < *ret.second)
        : (len1 < len2);
}
```

Or, in C++14 and later:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

bool String::operator < (const String &s) const 
{
    int len1 = this->getLength();
    int len2 = s.getLength();
    const char* buffer_end = this->buffer + len1;
    const char* s_end = s.buffer + len2;
    auto ret = std::mismatch(this->buffer, buffer_end, s.buffer, e_end);
    return ((ret.first != buffer_end) && (ret.second != s_end))
        ? (*ret.first < *ret.second)
        : (len1 < len2);
}
```

Comment: In the second one you giving,  "if (this->buffer[i] != s[i]) { return (this->buffer[i] < s[i]) }". So  how can we return this->buffer[i] < s[i] if they are only != each other?

Comment: @HoangMy in your original code, when the 1st loop detects `this->buffer[i]` is not equal to `s[i]`, it saves `i` to `index` (btw, you miss `break` after that), which then makes the subsequent loops useless. They will iterate only 0 or 1 time at most, always calling `return (true|false)` if 1 time, since `this->buffer[i]` is guaranteed to be either less-than or greater-then `s[i]` at `i == index`, since the 1st loop ensures that `this->buffer[i]` is not equal to `s[i]` at `i == index`. Hence why I removed the 2nd and 3rd loops entirely and merged those `return`s into the 1st loop directly.

Comment: is there any way I can chat with you? there are things I want to ask. hope you don't mind